# How to call the same random values as previous iterations?

Tags: python

I'm doing this:

```
random.randint(90, 110)
```

Pretty basic, returns values between 90 and 110 randomly.

However, I'm running the code 30 times, and I want these random values to change during the first 10 iterations, but I want the next 10 to change the same way as the previous 10 (i.e. random values in 11th/21st iteration are the same as the ones in 1st iteration, 12th/22nd = 2nd, etc.).

I tried to use random.seed(), so that the seed changes through iterations and tried to manipulate it so that the seed is the same for the 1st and the 11th/21st iterations. This does not seem to work though, as random.seed() seems to only work once.

Any way of doing this or does this not make sense?

EDIT: This is how I tried to do it using random.seed():

```
i = 0
while i < 30:
    if i < 10:
        sd = 100+i
    elif (i >= 10) and (i < 20):
        sd = 100+i-10
    elif i >= 20:
        sd = 100+i-20

    random.seed(sd)
```

Comment: So you want 1st, 11th, 21st iterations to return same value, similarly, 2nd, 12th and 22nd and so on?

Comment: Yes. I want them to be random values between 90/110, but the same values in those iterations.

Comment: Not sure what your seed calculations are intended to do, but if you save the state using `state = randon.getstate()` first and then use `random.setstate(st)` later, you should get the same random numbers after setting the state as before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea of using random seed is correct; you could implement it like this:

Every 10 iterations, the seed is reset, and the sequence of pseudo-random numbers restarts from the beginning.

```
import random


SEED = 1234


for idx in range(30):

    if idx % 10 == 0:
        random.seed(SEED)
        print()
    print(random.randrange(90, 110), end= ' ')
```

#### output:

```
94 103 99 106 106 95 95 106 110 108 
94 103 99 106 106 95 95 106 110 108 
94 103 99 106 106 95 95 106 110 108
```

Comment: I forgot to mention in my post that I'm working with lists, sorry. This solution works, but I'm struggling to adapt it to the use of lists - same scenario, except there's 30 lists. Random values within each list, and then the 1st list should be the same as the 11th/21st list, etc. Could you help me change it for this?

Comment: ok, cool, glad you were able to use my suggestion, and make it work for you.

Answer (score 0):

First generate the 30 seeds with the kind of repetition you want and then set the seeds before you generate the random number.

```
import random

seeds = np.arange(10)
seeds = np.hstack((seeds,seeds,seeds))

for i in range(30):

    random.seed(seeds[i])
    if i%10 ==0:
        print()
    print(random.randint(90, 110),end=' ')
```

output:

```
102 94 91 97 97 109 108 100 97 104 
102 94 91 97 97 109 108 100 97 104 
102 94 91 97 97 109 108 100 97 104
```

Answer (score 0):

Without `random.seed`, you could do it using a list-comprehension and `join`.

*Find first 10 randoms and then duplicate them to equal 30 count.*

```
import random

randoms = []

for _ in range(10):
    randoms.append(random.randint(90, 110))

print('\n'.join([' '.join(map(str, randoms)) for _ in range(3)]))

# 110 108 93 104 98 101 95 99 104 94
# 110 108 93 104 98 101 95 99 104 94                             
# 110 108 93 104 98 101 95 99 104 94
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code that works. I used array to store first 10 random entries and used i%10 to get appropriate value everytime

```
import random
random_arr=[] # 10 random numbers will be stored here
for i in range(10):
    random_arr.append(random.randint(10,90))

i = 0
while(i < 30):
    random_value = random_arr[i%10]
    print(random_value,end=" ")
    i+=1
```

OUTPUT:

```
32 27 28 86 11 54 26 24 38 16 32 27 28 86 11 54 26 24 38 16 32 27 28 86 11 54 26 24 38 16
```